# Send confirmation mail with user registration

Tags: laravel

```
    I try to register user with send connfirmation mail at the samme time.but the page is reloaded there is no data stored in db and also not sending the confirmation email.
```

RegisterController.php
         protected function create(array $data)
            {
               return User::create([
                    'title' => $data['title'],
                    'fname' => $data['fname'],
                    'lname' => $data['lname'],
                    'company' => $data['company'],
                    'email' => $data['email'],
                    'phone' => $data['phone'],
                    'people' => $data['people'],
                    'sdate' => $data['sdate'],
                    'notes' => $data['note'],
                    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
                ]);
            }
            public function register(Request $request)
            {
                //dd($request->all());
                $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

```
            event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

            Mail::to($user->email)->send(new ConfirmationEmail($user));

            return back()->with('status','Please confirm your email address...');
            // $this->guard()->login($user);

            // return $this->registered($request, $user)
            //                 ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
        }
//confirmation email code
        public function confirmEmail($token)
        {
            User::whereToken($token)->firstOrFail()->confirmEmail();

            return redirect('/user/login')->with('status', 'You are now confirmed. Please login.');
        }
```

Comment: Try `php artisan make:auth` first

Comment: auth.php
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

Comment: did you try composer dumpautoload -o ? and what is your laravel version?

Comment: how to solve it?

Comment: please anyone,help me to solve ?